# How to patch a function imported from another module

Tags: python, testing, boto3, patch, python-mock

Not able to patch the function.

I am trying to patch a function from another module in my test function. But I am not able to do that.

response.py

```
import boto3
lambda = boto3.client('lambda')

def response(event,context):
      s = boto3.client('s')
```

test_response.py

```
class lambda_handler(unittest.Testcae):
      @patch('response.boto3')
      test_handler():
       #doing the necessary assertions.
```

But the above mentioned one gives me the following error

```
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

The error is shown for the `boto3.client` declared outside the response function.
Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all fix the typo in here class lambda_handler(unittest.Testcae): on Testcase
Also `boto3.client` needs a parameter `region`. i.e.:

```
import boto3
lambda = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-west-2')

def response(event,context):
      s = boto3.client('s')
```

Comment: Do I have to necessarily give an argument like that?

Comment: @nithin11 seems so! It's the region you are connecting to.

Comment: I am patching boto3.client, so does the region_name matter then? I am a newbie . What I am asking maybe foolish. Sorry for the trouble.